# Rename a dozen files to a dozen specific, different filenames

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

I have a list of files. These files are all the same, but they need to be renamed so that their names are identical to another list of files. The filenames they require are all different.

Basically, I want to copy a load of filenames, and paste them onto a load of files to rename them. What utility can do that for me?

Windows 7, free program please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task I recommend [Advanced Renamer](http://alternativeto.net/software/advanced-renamer/).
Generate a list with the old filenames and the new filenames like this:

```
oldFilename1.old;newFilename1.new
oldFilename2.old;newFilename2.new
oldFilename3.old;newFilename3.new
oldFilename4.old;newFilename4.new
```

and save it as **renameList.csv**.

Start Advanced Renamer and choose Import - CSV File.
Select the renameList.csv as **Filename**.
Select the input folder of your files as **Base folder for original files**.

[image: CSV Import in Advanced Renamer]

Press **Import**.

You can even edit the list now if you want.

[image: Before batch execution]

If you are happy, press **START BATCH**.

Comment: But do they work how I said?

Comment: After having it verfied please up-vote my answer and mark it as accepted using the green checkmark.

Comment: As soon as I get the chance, I will report back. But I appreciate the effort, so here in any case, so here you go